# Prevent initialization with parentheses or braces

Tags: c++, constructor

Given a class `C`, is it possible to prevent construction using parenthesis (e.g. forbid `C c(1);`) or braces (e.g. forbid `C c{1};`)?

---

I am interested in the question per se, but since it got asked what is my motivation:

I do not like the following behaviours:

```cpp
#include <array>
struct aggregate{ int x,y; };
int main() {
  aggregate A{1};
  std::array< aggregate, 2 > B{1,2,3};
}
```

which yields

1. `A.x=1`, `A.y=0`
2. `B[0].x=1`, `B[0].y=2`,`B[1].x=3`, `B[1].y=0`

The first one is at least kind of reasonable, the second one not at all. I rather would like to have a compile time error for both of them.

My goal is to write a container `array` similar to (and as efficient as) `std::array` which prevents such bad constructions.

To be constructed like:

```cpp
#include <array>
struct aggregate{ int x,y; };
int main() {
  array< aggregate, 2 > A; // all elements default initialized
  array< aggregate, 2 > B{aggregate{1,2},aggregate{3,4}};
  array< aggregate, 2 > C{{1,2},{3,4}};  // would be nice but not mandatory

  // everything below here should yield compile time errors
  array< aggregate, 2 > D(1,2);
  array< aggregate, 2 > D{1,2};
  array< aggregate, 2 > D({1,2});
  array< aggregate, 2 > D(1,2,3,4);
  array< aggregate, 2 > D{1,2,3,4};
  // etc...

}
```

---

To further detalize my motivation (since it seems, my question is not going to be answered): I am not so concerned about the class `aggregate` given above, but about the class `array`. Thus, it is not an option to remove/add ctors from the class.

So far I have the following code:
It prevents nearly all of my unwanted initializations, except that it calls unnecessary often a ctor. So my idea is: In Debug mode I typedef `array` to the class ``` tmm::array`` in the code below, in Release mode I typedef it to ``` std::array`. But the problem arises that` tmm::array`allows constructs which are not allowed for`std::array`.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
inline constexpr bool areT_v = std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T,Ts>...>;

struct CLASS {
    int x, y;
    CLASS() noexcept { 
        std::cout << "default constructed" << std::endl; 
    }
    CLASS(int x_,int y_) noexcept : x(x_), y(y_) { 
        std::cout << "constructed" << std::endl; 
    }
    CLASS( CLASS const & other ) noexcept : x(other.x), y(other.y) {
        std::cout << "copy constructed" << std::endl; 
    }
};

namespace tmm {
    template< typename T, int rows >
    struct array
    {
        template< typename ... L > constexpr inline
        array( L && ... lst ) noexcept : content{ std::forward< L >( lst ) ... } {
            static_assert( sizeof...(L) == rows || sizeof...(L)==0 );
            static_assert( areT_v<T,L...>, "" );
        }
        array() = default;  // not sure whether I need this one
        T content[rows];
    };
}

int main() {
    #define INIT CLASS{1,2},CLASS{3,4},CLASS{5,6}
    std::array<CLASS,3>tb3b {INIT};  // 3 ctors
    tmm::array<CLASS,3> sb3b {INIT};  // 3 ctors and 3 copy ctors
    
//  std::array<CLASS,3> sp3a (INIT);  // does not compile
    tmm::array<CLASS,3>tp3a (INIT);   // compiles
}
```

Comment: What is your *actual* problem? Why do you need to prevent such construction?

Comment: And to prevent it, why not just remove any parameterized constructor from the class?

Comment: Could you explain (provide a code) how do you initialize class `C` and what type of initialization you need to block?

Comment: Even a non-parameterized constructor would allow `C c{};`

Comment: You could try creating a `delete`d constructor taking an `std::initializer_list<T>`

Comment: It seems you want to forbid aggregate initialization... Then just provide appropriate constructors.

Comment: Okay, then why not add actual constructors to the structure? The structure will no longer be a true aggregate, but it will disallow the cases you want to forbid.

Comment: As others have said, adding the appropriate (two) constructors prevents all your `D` forms (but also the `C` form). But then, your `aggregate` class isn't actually an aggregate type.

Comment: @Jarod42 With the solution for the container I currently have, I actually want to forbid the `()` initialization.

Comment: In C++20 you can just declare `default` constructor to make the struct non-aggregare. Note however that GCC has a lot bugs in this area, so test that what works for you

Answer (score 1):

> Given a class `C`, is it possible to prevent construction using parenthesis (e.g. forbid `C c(1);`) or braces (e.g. forbid `C c{1};`)?

To answer your question directly, the object of class `C` will only be constructible with the constructors you provide. That is, if `C` does not have a constructor from a single `int`, it won't be constructible using either `C c(1);` or `C c{1};` syntax.

There are a few caveats, especially given your later explanation. First, if your class `C` is an aggregate then it follows the standard language rules for initialization (that is, it allows [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)). You cannot have an aggregate class and prohibit its aggregate initialization at the same time. The only way around it is to specify the constructors you want to allow, at which point the class is no longer an aggregate:

```
struct C
{
    int x,y;

    C() : x(0), y(0) {}
    C(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

C a(10); // error - no constructor from a single int
```

Next, type conversions may still happen as part of initialization. If you also want to prohibit those, you may use [deleted constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) or [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). For example:

```
struct C_no_float
{
    int x,y;

    C_no_float() : x(0), y(0) {}
    C_no_float(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    C_no_float(double x, double y) = delete;
};

C_no_float a(10, 20); // ok
C_no_float b(1.0, 2.0); // error - calling a deleted constructor
```

Note that using deleted functions may still be error-prone since the constructor from `int`s may still be called as a result of type conversion. In other words, this approach does not guarantee that `C_no_float` is not constructible from anything but exactly a pair of `int`s. Using SFINAE allows for stronger restriction on argument types:

```
struct C_only_int
{
    int x,y;

    C_only_int() : x(0), y(0) {}
    template< typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>> >
    C_only_int(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

C_only_int a(10, 20); // ok, T is int
C_only_int b(10l, 20l); // error - T would be long,
                        // template argument substitution fails
```